# Calculate age from birth date using doctrine query language

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

I am working in Zend Framework 2 and using Doctrine Query Language.

I have to add the filter for age on user listing page. In the database I have stored the date of birth of users using date format. Please help me how can I use the where condition to apply my filter.

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('User\Entity\User');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u');
$query->where("(DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), u.birth_date)/365)=".$search_arr['age']);
```

This query is not returning anything. The reason might be that when I run it in mysql `DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE( ) , u.birth_date ) /365`, it returns number of years in float e.g 10.29. I need to convert it to integer to compare. Mysql provides **FLOOR** function but its not working in DQL.

Please help me regarding it.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) solution?

Comment: @DainisAbols I have tried this solution. But it gives me the error that FLOOR function is not available in DQL.

Comment: You have to define a custom DQL function: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html

Answer (score 0):

The following formula is doing the trick for me:

```
if (today - 31 <= DOB >= today - 30) i am 30.
```

This is what it looks like in DQL:

```
$age = intval($data['age']);

$startDate = new \DateTime('now');
$startDate->modify('-'.($age+1).' years');

$endDate = new \DateTime('now');
$endDate->modify('-'.$age.' years');
$from = new \DateTime($startDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$to   = new \DateTime($endDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('p');
$qb->from('MyBundle:Person', 'p');
$qb->andWhere('p.dateOfBirth BETWEEN :from AND :to');
$qb->setParameter('from', $from);
$qb->setParameter('to', $to);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->createQueryBuilder('u')->where(':year - substring(u.birthday,1,4) = :age and ((:month = substring(u.birthday,6,2) and :day >= substring(u.birthday,9,2)) or :month > substring(u.birthday,6,2)) or 
        :year - substring(u.birthday,1,4) - 1 = :age and ((:month = substring(u.birthday,6,2) and :day < substring(u.birthday,9,2)) or :month < substring(u.birthday,6,2))')

        ->setParameter('year', (new \DateTime('now'))->format("Y"))
        ->setParameter('month', (new \DateTime('now'))->format("m"))
        ->setParameter('day', (new \DateTime('now'))->format("d"))
        ->setParameter('age', $age);
```

format of date Y-m-d